# Read and convert modbus tcp with node-red

Tags: modbus, data-processing

I try to convert modbus tcp data formats in different types like Bool/Float/String/U16/U32 and S16/S32.

If I understand S16 and S32 are custom data formats of the manufacturer.

[image: Legend of Data Formats]

For the float I follow this guide [Reading 32 bit Float from modbus TCP using node red](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56257673/reading-32-bit-float-from-modbus-tcp-using-node-red) and it's work fine.

Someone can explain me how to do the same for the others types of data ?

Here is my flow

[image: MyFlow]

The full PDF of the modbus server is here:
http://cloudzola.quickconnect.to/d/f/560350335902727299

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same way as described in the answer you linked to.

Just instead of calling `readFloatBE()` you want to call `readInt16BE()` on the buffer.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readint16le_offset) for the NodeJS Buffer object for the different available methods to read/write different sized fields.